# A Primary Index must be a non-unique on all the partitioned tables. why is that? Teradata

Tags: indexing, teradata, partitioning

A Primary Index must be a non-unique on all the partitioned tables unless the the Primary Index Column is also used to define the partition.

[image]

For unique-primary index with partition by:

```
    CREATE Set TABLE Order_Table_CPPI
(Order_Number      INTEGER Not Null
,Customer_Number   INTEGER
,Order_Date        DATE
,Order_Total       Decimal (10,2)
)UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(Order_Number, Order_Total)
  PARTITION BY CASE_N
   ( Order_Total < 1000,
     Order_Total < 5000,
     Order_Total < 10000,
     Order_Total < 20000,
     NO Case OR UNKNOWN);
```

I am wondering that: is there any specific logic behind this or its just hard coded fact? Thanks.

Comment: If the partitioning column is not part of the PI the system needs to check *every* partition for that unique combination, there's no efficient way to do this

Comment: I thought it only needs to check 1 partition, not all?

Comment: I got it. thanks for your replies.  :)

Comment: @access_granted a single partition will be scanned only if a filter of some sort is set on selection. If UPI columns are not part of partition definition and a UPI based query is performed, then system would have to check in each partition. That is inefficient and hence not allowed because UPI access is expected to be really fast

Comment: I got it. Thank you :)